# How to calculate RMSE of geographic coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, statistics, accuracy

I've been working on my project and I stumble upon how I can calculate the Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) of geographic coordinates.

What I have is a derived coordinates from processing LiDAR data and aerial images in ArcMap and I also have actual field-measured coordinates. But now I am lost on how I could measure the error between the derived coordinates and field-measured coordinates.

Any help?

Furthermore, is there a specific format of the geographic coordinates where I could calculate the error? I am currently using the DD format.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate RMSE of geographic coordinates the same way you would calculate it in a projected coordinate system. The only catch is that if you're using decimal degrees, the RMSE will be in decimal degrees as well. In geographic coordinates, decimal degrees is far better than degrees-minutes-seconds, in my opinion.

You have to make two columns each for X, Y and Z: your derived coordinates and your measured coordinates. You subtract the derived coordinates from the measured coordinates to get an estimation of error. You'll end up with three separate columns, one for X error, one for Y error and one for Z error.

I've used this kind of system in the past for calculating RMSE in a spreadsheet: [Using Excel to calculate the RMSE for LiDAR vertical ground control points](http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2010/05/using-excel-to-calculate-rmse-for-lidar.html). This specifically outlines calculation of error in Z, but can be applied to X and Y in the same way. The formula looks like this:

```
=SQRT(SUMSQ(A2:A18)/COUNTA(A2:A18))
```

The square root of the sum of squares of your error divided by the number of observations, obviously substituting A2 and A18 with the range of your estimated error data. You'll then have three values: an X RMSE, a Y RMSE and a Z RMSE.

Alternatively, if you want a more intuitive measurement, you could just reproject the geographic coordinates into a more local system that better suits your needs.